# set var value css in html

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I am migrating an application from Ionic 1 to Ionic 4 and I have a problem with css (I do not understand much about css and styles), create a variable in variables.scss

```
--my-color-secondary: #5BC500;
```

And I need an ion-button to take that value, but I do not succeed, however if I create the button like this:

```
<ion-button color="primary">Go</ion-button>
```

Take the default value defined in `--ion-color-primary: #3880ff;`

Comment: If you have a scss file, it mean that you are using sass, and the syntax for creating sass variables is `$my-color-secondary: #5BC500` for example

Answer (score 0):

First `color` isn't a valid HTML attribute. Ionic "may" convert that for you but I doubt it. You should either apply a `class="myClass"` or an inline `style=""`

---

**CSS variables MUST BE applied inside of a style declaration.** Typically this means Inside a style block (or imported stylesheet) like so:

```
--main-bg-color: #cc0000;

.className {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

You can also SET the variable value inline like so:

```css
button {
  color: var(--myTextColor);
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #dadada;
}
```

```html
<button style="--myTextColor: #cc0000;">Button</button>
```

This Requires separate styling targeting the element where the variable is set.

***Note:*** The variable WILL NOT work outside the scope of the element with the inline styles.